# How to schedule the java CRON job Infor EAM?

Tags: infor-eam

I need to run the CRON  job for every one minute in the Infor-EAM . i have my java program jar and other dependent jars deployed in the server and i created a new job and trying it to schedule it for every 1 min.

when i run the CRON  job manually (clicking on "Run Job" job is running successfully) but when i schedule it for 1 one min, it is not running for every one min. can someone help me how to schedule the job for every 1 min in Infor-EAM?  thanks in advance.

The parameter i used in the setup of job in InforEAM is

java -cp E:\inforEAM\EAMCMX\prog\EAMCMX_INTERFACE.jar;E:\inforEAM\EAMCMX\prog\sqljdbc4-3.0.jar; com.gsk.eam.cmx.scheduler.EamCmxOutboundJob EAMOUT

Answer (score 0):

This Will help you,

```
INSERT INTO r5schedules (sch_code, sch_name, sch_description, sch_type, sch_month, sch_dayofmonth, sch_hour, sch_minute)
    VALUES ('Code of JOB', 'Name', 'Description', 'C', NULL, NULL, NULL, '0-59/1');
```

Answer (score 0):

the parameter that you used for the cron job is having issue. it should have all the depend jar files and your code jar file as well. check it properly